# Find the adjoint of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been working in this exercise, and I may have found a *partial* solution, but I have doubts about it.

Let  : ⟶  on a Hilbert space (,⟨.,.⟩) with V being $P_4[\Bbb R]$, using the inner product $$⟨,⟩=\int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x)dx$$ and let T be $T(f(x))=xf'(x)$.

I need to find the adjoint of T. I've tried using the definition of the adjoint, but I get $$⟨T,⟩=\int_{-1}^1 xf'(x)g(x)dx = xf(x)g(x)\Biggl|_{-1}^1-\int_{-1}^1f(x)\big[xg'(x)+g(x)\big]dx$$ and I can't figure how to get rid of $xf(x)g(x)\Bigl|_{-1}^1$.

I also have tried using the associated matrix of the transformation with respect a basis formed by the first 5 Legendre polynomials, thus using its transpose to find the adjoint 
$$[T^*] = [T]^T =\begin {pmatrix}  
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}^T =
\begin {pmatrix}  
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$ then $ \forall$ $ v \in V, \exists$ $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$,  $a_4$, $a_5 \in\Bbb R$ such that $v=a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + a_3u_3 + a_4u_4 + a_5u_5$ where $u_i$ are the first 5 Legendre polynomials, I can define the adjoint as $$T^*(v) = \bigg(a_2 + \frac 35 a_4\bigg)u_2 + \bigg(a_1 + \frac 53 a_3 + \frac {53}{35} a_5\bigg)u_3 + \bigg(3a_2 + 3 a_4\bigg)u_4 + \bigg(4a_1 + \frac {14}{35} a_3 + \frac {184}{35} a_5 \bigg)u_5$$
Can the last expression be called the *adjoint* of the operator? 
Is there another way to find the adjoint that I'm not aware of?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you prefer the Legendre polynomials to just $1,x,\dots,x^4$ in this context? The matrix of $T$ with respect to monomials is much simpler. Do you have $a=-1$, $b=1$ so the Legendre polynomials form an orthogonal basis?

Comment: Becuase the Legendre polynomials already form an orthormal basis, for 1,,…,$^4$ you would to orthonormalize them first, although it could work, and for a and b, yes they are -1 and 1, i'll edit them.

Comment: The way I know the Legendre polynomials they start with $P_0 = 1$, which is not of norm $1$, so they are only an orthogonal basis. Do you have a different convention? Also: Please don't use $x$ both a the degree $1$ polynomial and as an arbitrary element of $V$.